# I want to detect iris and measure its diameter in python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, iris-recognition

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoY4e.jpg)I used mediapipe for detecting iris in python ,it detects and the problem is if eye closed means circle found around the iris and how to overcome this and measure the iris diameter
It detects iris in realtime ,i used web cam  for detecting iris ,if any movement happened two circles found and how to overcome this error

And this is my code

> ```
> import cv2 as cv
> import numpy as np
> import mediapipe as mp
>
> mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh
>
> LEFT_EYE = [362, 382, 381, 380, 374, 373, 390, 249, 263, 466, 388, 387, 386, 385, 384, 398]
> RIGHT_EYE = [33, 7, 163, 144, 145, 153, 154, 155, 133, 173, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 246]
>
> # irises Indices list
> LEFT_IRIS = [474, 475, 476, 477]
> RIGHT_IRIS = [469, 470, 471, 472]
>
> cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
>
> with mp_face_mesh.FaceMesh(
>         max_num_faces=1,
>         refine_landmarks=True,
>         min_detection_confidence=0.5,
>         min_tracking_confidence=0.5
> ) as face_mesh:
>     while True:
>         ret, frame = cap.read()
>         if not ret:
>             break
>         frame = cv.flip(frame, 1)
>
>         rgb_frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
>         img_h, img_w = frame.shape[:2]
>         results = face_mesh.process(rgb_frame)
>         mask = np.zeros((img_h, img_w), dtype=np.uint8)
>
>         if results.multi_face_landmarks:
>           
>
>             mesh_points = np.array([np.multiply([p.x, p.y], [img_w, img_h]).astype(int)
>                                     for p in results.multi_face_landmarks[0].landmark])
>
>        
>
>             (l_cx, l_cy), l_radius = cv.minEnclosingCircle(mesh_points[LEFT_IRIS])
>             (r_cx, r_cy), r_radius = cv.minEnclosingCircle(mesh_points[RIGHT_IRIS])
>             center_left = np.array([l_cx, l_cy], dtype=np.int32)
>             center_right = np.array([r_cx, r_cy], dtype=np.int32)
>             cv.circle(frame, center_left, int(l_radius), (0, 255, 0), 2, cv.LINE_AA)
>             cv.circle(frame, center_right, int(r_radius), (0, 255, 0), 2, cv.LINE_AA)
>
>             cv.circle(mask, center_left, int(l_radius), (255, 255, 255), -1, cv.LINE_AA)
>             cv.circle(mask, center_right, int(r_radius), (255, 255, 255), -1, cv.LINE_AA)
>
>         cv.imshow('Mask', mask)
>         cv.imshow('img', frame)
>         key = cv.waitKey(1)
>         if key == ord('q'):
>             break
> cap.release()
> cv.destroyAllWindows()
> ```

Comment: Please show your images

Comment: I uploaded the sample image